# How to ensure my website loads all resources via https?

Tags: ssl, https

URL in question: https://newyorkliquorgiftshop.com/admin/

When you open the above page, you can see in the console that there are lots of error messages saying "...was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet.."

This website was working well until all of a sudden this problem shows up. I am not very familiar with https, but I have contacted with Godaddy and the SSL certificate is valid, and there is no obvious problem with "https://newyorkliquorgiftshop.com"[image]. And I am stuck here, I've some experiences with HTTPS website before, if the URL of website's homepage is "https", then every resources it loads is via "https" too. I don't know why my website behave differently and I don't know where to start to solve the problem? Any hint is appreciated especially articles about HTTPS that is related to my problem.(I have done a brief research regarding HTTPS but most of the articles I found are about the basic concepts.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the code (not sure what you built the website using), try using https instead of http for the URL's you use to load your style sheets and script files.

For example one of the errors is

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://newyorkliquorgiftshop.com/admin/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.newyorkliquorgiftshop.com/admin/view/javascript/common.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

You are requesting the .js file using HTTP, try using HTTPS like so:

```
https://www.newyorkliquorgiftshop.com/admin/view/javascript/common.js
```

Comment: its opencart 2.0, which is very old but the site owner doesn't want to upgrade it and I have to work with it. 
I am not very familiar with php either, I am looking for where the resources are loaded but since the site was working well I think simply hacking code is not the right solution

Comment: Okay fair enough, But I believe this is why you are getting those errors, I haven't used Opencart myself and I'm not sure if there is a way to specify to load all resources over HTTPS

Comment: Up until a little while ago you could have mixed content on a site.  Not now, it gets blocked completely, that's probably why you just noticed.  If you can find a 'base url' setting, you might be able to simply change it from http:// to https://.  If not,  what I'd recommend is pulling down the code/database and parsing through it to replace any hardlinks using http:// to https://.  Be careful not to swap external links.